# When would GKMatchRequest be 'invalid'?

Tags: ios8, game-center, gamekit, gkmatchmaker

Occasionally, but not rarely, the `findMatchForRequest:withCompletionHandler:` returns with  error 13 or `GKErrorMatchRequestInvalid`:
"The requested operation could not be completed because the match request is invalid."

The documentation only says:

> **GKErrorMatchRequestInvalid**
>
> The match request’s properties are
>   impossible to fulfill. For example, the minimum number of players
>   cannot be larger than the maximum number of players. Available in iOS
>   4.0 and later.

I *think* that `GKErrorMatchRequestInvalid` never occurs on *1st* try, that is, when directly after launching from Xcode, but only on 2nd/3rd/... tries. Happens on either the device or the simulator. So I assume that I *am* doing something wrong, but what? **Is there an *exhaustive* list of conditions under which `GKMatchRequest` is invalid?**

Tried to recover from `GKErrorMatchRequestInvalid` by recalling `findMatchForRequest:`, but never succeed: **once I get an 'invalid' `match`, then all further `findMatchForRequest:` calls also return with an 'invalid' `match`**. Trying to remedy this by using both `[[GKMatchmaker sharedMatchmaker] cancel]` and `[[GKMatchmaker sharedMatchmaker] finishMatchmakingForMatch:` ... obviously, I don't even have a valid `match` to `finishMatchmakingFor:`.

The matchmaking happens in a singleton (if that matters). Here's the relevant code:

```
GKMatchRequest *request = [GKMatchRequest new];
request.minPlayers = 3;
request.maxPlayers = 4;

[[GKMatchmaker sharedMatchmaker] findMatchForRequest:request withCompletionHandler:^(GKMatch *match, NSError *error)
 {
     if (error)
     {
         if (error.code == 503                          ||
             error.code == GKErrorMatchRequestInvalid   ||
             error.code == GKErrorNotAuthenticated      ||
             error.code == GKErrorCommunicationsFailure ||
             error.code == GKErrorUnknown               ||
             error.code == GKErrorInvalidPlayer         ||
             error.code == GKErrorInvalidParameter      ||
             error.code == GKErrorAuthenticationInProgress)
         {               
             [self.delegate restartMatchmaking];
         }
     }
     else if (match)
     {
        // happy-path
     }
 }];
```

Answer (score 1):

I get the same exact thing.  And ran the same tests.  This seems to be really, "Request can not be submitted" and Not related to REQUEST contents are invalid/incorrect.

Suspected reasons:

- An authentication issue (maybe did not re-authenticate)
- Maybe MatchMaker thinks a request (last request) is still active. (was GameCenter restarted while waiting for a match?) I could not find a way to query matchmaker to see if a request is active.
- MayBe MatchMaker CANCEL is hitting some timing hole and not being accepted/Completed.
- Maybe a hosed up state, where the request can not be submitted to (or accepted by) MatchMaker (most likely)

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem, and realized that I had `minPlayers=1`.

After setting `minPlayers=2` everything worked fine. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and solved it by calling `[[GKMatchmaker sharedMatchmaker] cancel];`.

This triggers an error in the `- (void)findMatchForRequest:(GKMatchRequest *)request withCompletionHandler:(void(^__nullable)(GKMatch * __nullable match, NSError * __nullable error))completionHandler;` completions handler.

```
NSLocalizedDescription = "The requested operation has been canceled or disabled by the user.";
```

Hope this helps.